# NextJS Back/Forward-button not working in Instagram Inline Safari

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a website using NextJS, wherein all links are using `next/link` for routing. However, when I visit the website via Instagram inframe Safari, the back-/forward-buttons does not work for the routing. They are grey like I haven't clicked on a link.

I have tried using

```
<Link href={blablabla} passHref>
   <a>
      {content}
   </a>
</Link>
```

But that does not solve the issue. Any thoughts on approach?

Comment: This isn't specifically related to Next.  This might be an SPA issue or at a minimum a React & Instagram's webview integration issue.  I opened a Next site and vanilla React site (router v5) via Instagram link and the webview's navigation buttons are greyed out on both. Internal routing works - but at the bottom do not.  I've never noticed until this post.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the problem.

I decided to not use next link on browser in Instagram app.

```js
const link = (
  <a href={href} target={target} rel={rel}>
    {children}
  </a>
);

// for browser in Instagram app (not working browser back on NextLink)
if (!navigator.userAgent.includes('Instagram')) return <NextLink href={href}>{link}</NextLink>;

return link;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide either a link to the deployed site or some additional code for more context? Based on your problem, you could try a hybridized approach as follows:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

//...
    const slug: string = 'example';
    const router = useRouter();
    // use z-index to ensure clickable link is in very front of z-axis
    // router.push('/instagram/[slug]', `instagram/${slug}`, {...}) === (href, as, { options })
    const example = (
        <div>
            <Link
                href='/instagram/[slug]'
                as={`/instagram/${slug}`}
                shallow={true}
                prefetch={true}
                passHref={true}
                scroll={true}
            >
                <a
                    className='z-150 group-hover:bg-opacity-90'
                    id={'troublesome link'}
                    onClick={() =>
                        router.push('/instagram/[slug]', `/instagram/${slug}`, {
                            shallow: true,
                            locale: 'en-US',
                            scroll: true
                        })
                    }
                >
                    <span className='sr-only'>
                        the larr and rarr notation below === left arrow and right
                        arrow, respectively. This text won't be visible on the DOM,
                        only for the screen reader
                    </span>
                    <p>&larr;&nbsp;&rarr;</p>
                </a>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
    console.log(
        `${
            (example.props,
            example.key,
            example.type ?? 'example not yet rendered or error')
        } `
    );
    //...
```

Note: Shallow routing only works if it is navigating between content hosted on the same page (even [...slug].tsx catch-all routes)

if this is the case, I definitely recommend utilizing shallow rendering

Another idea is to make all active-links a bright color to test whether they are indeed active (aria-active) or not in that particular DOM environment. Use an animation like ping to see if the `aria-current` clone is emitting light in the DOM.

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React, {
    FC,
    JSXElementConstructor,
    ReactElement
} from 'react';
import css from '../Button/button.module.css'

export const NavLink: FC = (children, href: string) => {
    const child = React.Children.only(
        children as ReactElement<
            { 'aria-current': string | null },
            string | JSXElementConstructor<any>
        >
    );
    const router = useRouter();
    const AriaCurrentCloneElement = (
        <Link href={href}>
            {React.cloneElement(child, {
                'aria-current': router.pathname === href ? 'page' : null
            })}
        </Link>
    );
    return <div className={css.clone}>{AriaCurrentCloneElement}</div>;
};
```

the corresponding css class, clone, is as follows:

```css
.clone {
    @apply flex justify-between;
    & a {
        @apply bg-current text-rojo-100 p-4 no-underline outline-none font-semibold;
        &:hover {
            @apply text-gray-900 duration-150 transition-colors ease-in-out transform-gpu;
        }
        &[aria-current] {
            @apply animate-slowPing font-bold text-lg text-rojo-300 transition-transform duration-300 ease-in-out;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. The active site is owcollection.com (go in via mobile, elsewise you'll be redirected). Thanks in advance!